# Web service is WSDL or REST or both?

Tags: web-services, rest, wsdl

I would like to know that web service clearly means the usage of WSDL file and SOAP protocol (mainly WSDL) or it may mean the REST API, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web services are programs that make data (typically XML or JSON) and operations on those data available over the HTTP protocol.

Whether the data is transferred via SOAP and whether the API os constructed as a REST API is not relevant to whether it is a web service. WSDL files describe interfaces of web services. They may describe SOAP services as well as REST services...

Comment: I have the same opinion about this, but according to one of my partners the web service is equal downloading WSDL file and generating proxy class from it and he has problems with REST because "It is not web service." Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a little bit confusing.

WSDL stands for Web Service Description Language, used to define SOAP Web Services.

Both SOAP and REST use http as protocol but, as far as I know you can't define a 'REST service' using WSDL. 'REST services' are refered as 'resources'.

Some tools use WADL (Web Application Description Language) to define REST resources, but it isn't as reliable as WSDL for generating clients and it isn't broadly accepted by the community.